# i cant make a cooldown on a CPS variable

Tags: python, pgzero

Here is the code:

```
 def update(dt):

    global puan,cps

    clock.schedule(cps, 1.0)

    puan += cps
```

here is the variable:

`cps = 0`

I tried making it increase puan variable by 1 every second but it ignored clock.schedule and its increasing it continously now.

i need some help.

thanks.

(im not using tkinter)